# Why is fetchContents(...) called when opening an already materialized file?

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

I am implementing a file provider based on [`NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension) on macOS. Currently I am working on the download of remote dataless files which works fine so far. It is materialized and available locally and the related [`NSFileProviderItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritem) object I provide to the system returns `true` for [`isDownloaded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritemprotocol/2879579-isdownloaded) and [`isMostRecentVersionDownloaded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritemprotocol/2879572-ismostrecentversiondownloaded).

When I open the plain text file in Finder in TextEdit, then it is actually opened by the app but almost immediately the system also calls [`fetchContents(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension/3553303-fetchcontents) on my extension object. I do not understand why because there is no need to fetch the contents.

I tried various ways to call the mandatory completion handler of `fetchContents(...)`, but apparently either a URL to a local content file and the `NSFileProviderItem` have to be provided **or** an `Error`.

Note: When opening the plain text file through Finder in TextEdit the [`modifyItem(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension/3656552-modifyitem) function on my file provider extension is called, too, to update the [`.lastUsedDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritemfields/3656545-lastuseddate). In that completion handler I provide `false` as the argument which tells the system to request the item contents.

How can I make clear that the system should not call `fetchContents(...)` for already downloaded files over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`modifyItem(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension/3656552-modifyitem) call I passed through the `NSFileProviderItem` argument provided by the system. That was my mistake. The item provided by the system does not have an [`itemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritemprotocol/3043896-itemversion) property defined as it is defined by the other `baseVersion` argument on `modifyItem(...)` and tracked by my own code. Returning my own `NSFileProviderItem` with the correct version information is the key for the system not requesting content retrieval again.

---

See also: [my crosspost in the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720243).